# none of views showing image

Tags: swift, xcode

not setting image on every views like UIView , UIImageView

```
mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "headerDriver.png")!)

img.image = UIImage(named: "about")
```

and there is warning in console

```
Driver was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
```

i have test it with image literal to make sure image exist
i suddenly deleted the optimization level and now drop down menu is gone i can't change the value of it

there is a problem with

> optimization level

in build setting i'm sure

Comment: You have to check that images are not nil. Just try to force unwrap them with an exclamation mark. Something like ‘img.image = UIImage(named: "about")!’.

Comment: not creative answer. unwrapping made it crash. and i'm using image literal and i'm sure image exist

Comment: It made crash it crash because these images are not accessible (basically, it crashed because it's impossible to create the UIImage with these names) and something is wrong with an asset catalogue. The code is fine.

Comment: how can i create new one ? delete and recreate

Comment: This step-by-step guide is nice - https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Adding-Image-Assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you mentioned if asset folder is not in compile resource.xcode will not compile it so your app crash because there is no asset folder either all you pictures

solution :

navigate your target -> build phases - > compile source -> add (+)